# Highstock/Highchart substep maximum?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiUht.png)

I want my maximum step count to cap at a dynamic integer. In this case it's 4. I went through the documentation but can't find anything that suits my needs. Does someone have an idea about this?

Ideally; I want the white space shown in red **gone**.

```
xAxis: {
    min: 1.1,
    ordinal: false,
    max: 2,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'Lap ' + this.value;
        },
    },
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d54uae3s/4/

Comment: Can you show us your code? Best would be creating a jsfiddle for it. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/d54uae3s/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `breaks` from the `broken-axis` Highcharts module:

```
function createBreaks() {
    var breaks = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        breaks.push({
            from: i + 0.4,
            to: i + 1.1,
            breakSize: 0.1
        })
    }

    return breaks;
}

var chart = Highcharts.chart({
    ...,
    xAxis: {
        ...
        breaks: createBreaks()
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sjLdfegp/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.breaks

Comment: This only affects the range slider. I need to stop the auto completion of data. It seems this issue only persist on HighStock.js ..

To be clear; I want it to display 1.1 till 1.4 and let it begin with 2.1

Comment: Hi @Marthijn, Ok, so I think that you should use the `breaks`. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pzna0gko/

Comment: This almost works, nice find! http://jsfiddle.net/Pondake/m4z3wv6t/1/

Setting it to repeat will make some points disappear, it also creates a laggy experience when using the range slider. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Marthijn, It seems that defined breaks work better than `repeat` option, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sjLdfegp/

Comment: Really nice, that works! The lag however remains while using the range slider. Can you update your original answer so I can accept the answer?

Comment: Hi @Marthijn, I am glad I could help. I have edited the answer.